# My headphone jack stopped working when I upgraded to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, audio-jack

I usually run sound from my laptop through my headphone jack into a mixer so I can listen to music through my big PA speakers. The moment I upgraded the OS, however, it stopped working when plugged in, no audio at all. Sound still comes through the laptop speakers when unplugged, though. I dual boot, so I logged into Windows and the sound worked fine. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Try [alsa](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page). You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-utils
```